# Can a MicroSD card work at 144 kHz or lower?

Tags: integrated-circuit, spi, 555, sd

Can a MicroSD memory card work at a 144 kHz or lower frequency? I want to read a text file that has a syntax that would be filtered and matched to a speaker. I would like to get data from the MicroSD but my circuit can't work with a high frequency.

I have a 144 kHz 555 IC and it had worked with a speaker after I wired it with a calculator, however I can't test a crystal oscillator circuit without a frequency counter.

Comment: You'd need a microcontroller in there somewhere to drive the microSD?

Comment: i know how spi works and i use my simple processing unit to filter data without processors but boobs.

Comment: everything work well,but you can't understand what is my design because just processor designers can.But i'm not sure if i can run it with low frequency,or not.

Comment: i use ic 4017,4070 to drive it.

Comment: You can parse the file system structure and read a file from the SD card  without a processor? There is a lot more to reading an SD card than just running an SPI bus.

Comment: i believe that i can read it because first,in theory, there's possible while text files aren't decoded in spi.I had viewed a text file with hex editor,the texts are plain text and related with hex code as well as the binary codes.

Comment: Yes parsing text in hardware is possible. But first you have to access the file. That involves parsing the file allocation table to find you where on the SD card it is stored and then requesting the correct block. That is the part that is hard to do in hardware.

Comment: You also need to initialise the SD card before you can do anything with it, and that takes special command sequences with properly timed delays.

Comment: I highly suspect you need a SD card(speed, complicity, wear-leveling management, power management) to do what you want to do. Consider some simpler rom architecture like NOR, FRAM or NVRAM(nvSRAM)?

Comment: I afraid 555 is not enough to read the SD card. You probably do not realize how complex file system implementation is. And it pointless. uC costs $1, even if you do in the discreet logic after several years of hard work, your hardware only will cost probably couple of hundreds + will consume power like the kettle

Answer (score 3):

An SD card that supports SPI can run at 144 kHz, in fact I've single-stepped through code that accesses an SD card using bit banging very slowly without problem. But you have some fundamental misunderstandings that mean this won't work:

- If you had an SPI device that sent data on every clock cycle then indeed you could use a 555 as the clock source and feed the data output to a speaker.
- However for a text file stored on an SD card you have to deal with the file structure as mentioned in a comment. But you can get raw access to a device under Windows and Linux so you could potentially write just the bitstream you're after to the SD card.
- But the real deal-breaker is what Tom Carpenter mentioned in a comment that SD cards need an initialization sequence before you can do anything with it, and while it's not too hard using a microcontroller it will be very difficult using discrete logic.

For example from the following [Simple FAT and SD Tutorial Part 3](http://codeandlife.com/2012/04/25/simple-fat-and-sd-tutorial-part-3/) the commands in BusPirate syntax are listed as:

1. Init and go to SPI mode: ]r:10 [0x40 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x95 r:8]
2. Initialize card: [0x41 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0xFF r:8]
3. Set transfer size: [0x50 0x00 0x00 0x02 0x00 0xFF r:8]
4. Read sector: [0x51 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0xFF r:520]

The above is very simplified, if you go through that tutorial from the start you'll see the many steps involved to just start being able to read from the card.

Comment: i very impressed with your comment.yes it looks like quite difficult.But i just want to explain that where i start thinking that i can handle file structure.First,i realized that every file with special format would have its format significant(3 hex)in top.i can write data behind a strings syntax,and then whenever that data is parsed,i will read the source code after that code.

Comment: The last part will be the hard part - until you send that sequence to an SD card it just won't work. Really you might be best to get something like an Arduino for a start and once you get that working you'll realize how hard it would have been without a microcontroller.